# Flatten lists in Prolog with additional clause

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm currently starting to learn Prolog and struggling to solve even basic problems.

My current assignment is to create a predicate that flattens a nested list. I'm not supposed to use the cut operator, an accumulator or `->` for this one.

My current predicate looks like this:

```
my_flatten(X,[X]) :- \+ is_list(X).
my_flatten([],[]).
my_flatten([X|Rest],Flattened) :- 
      my_flatten(X,Xflat), 
      my_flatten(Rest,Restflat), 
      append(Xflat,Restflat,Flattened).
```

This works as expected for most inputs. However the query `my_flatten(abc, [abc])` returns `true` instead of `false`.
So element 1 must be a list, that would however interfere with rule 1 which marks the bottom of the nested list recursion.

Edit:

```
flattenx([],[]).
flattenx([H|T], R) :- flattenx(H, FH), append(FH, FT, R) , flattenx(T, FT).
flattenx([H|T], R) :- \+ flattenx(H, FH), R = [H|FT], flattenx(T, FT).
```

Comment: Well since `abc` is *not* a list, the first predicate fires.

Comment: Yes I get it so far. However I don't know how to ignore this rule at the initial step for example.

Comment: It might be easier to only flatten things you know are lists, rather than trying to gin up a way to flatten things that aren't lists. After all, if it's not a list, you can just put it in the result without further processing.

Comment: note that `\+` (and `->`) is just syntax sugar on `!`

Comment: in general, we do such things by introducing an *interface* predicate, with a different name / arity, as called for by the situation at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first clause is not really necessary: it wraps anything that is *not* a list, in a list constructor. You probably do *not* want that.

In essence, there are *three* things that can happen:

1. we have an empty list, then flattening it, will return an empty list;
2. we have a non-empty list, and the first item is a list as well, then we first flatten that sublist, and continue with the list; and
3. we have a non-empty list, and the first item is *not* a list, then we continue flattining.

This results in the following predicate:

```
flatten([], []).
flatten([H|T], R) :-
    (
       flatten(H, FH)
    -> append(FH, FT, R)
    ;  R = [H|FT]
    ),
    flatten(T, FT).
```

The above is however not very elegant, nor is it very efficient, and it works only in *one* direction. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I'm currently not allowed to use `->` in my predicates. I would appreciate any hints for a solution without it. I can't seem to find a way without using `flatten(X,[X]) ...`.

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti: well then you need to "flatten" the if-then-else. How would you translate `p(X) -> q(X); r(X)` in disjunctive normal form.

Comment: `(p(X) AND q(X)) OR (NOT p(X) AND r(X))` should be the disjunctive normal form of an If-then-else. Yet I still struggle to express this in Prolog.

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti: the "or" can be implemented by defining two clauses, one for the first, and one for the other. The *not* is in Prolog `\+`, although the two are a bit "different" semantically.

Comment: Okay I think I'm on it. I updated the question with my current solution. Could you maybe take a look at it?

Comment: @JohnnyKonfetti: yes, this looks like the solution :)

Comment: Thank you very much! The connection to boolean algebra helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer just to evidence that your prerequisites are not (strictly) satisfied by the solution you posted after the *Edit:* paragraph, because `\+` (and `->`, i.e. if-then-else) is just syntax sugar to make cut' usage a bit less error prone. You could instead explicit patterns in the head, to guide clause selection. For instance

```
flatten_no_cut([],[]).
flatten_no_cut([[A|As]|Xs],Fs) :-
    flatten_no_cut([A|As],Gs),
    flatten_no_cut(Xs,Es),
    append(Gs,Es,Fs).
flatten_no_cut([X|Xs],[X|Ys]) :-
    flatten_no_cut(Xs,Ys).
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The `\+` operator was explicitly mentioned in my assignment (and so was not using cut). So I think the solution I posted in the edit is fine for my case.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions posted by Carlo and Willem are incorrect in the presence of variables in the list to be flatted. E.g.

```
?- flatten([A,B,C], Flatted).
A = B, B = C, C = Flatted, Flatted = [].
```

or:

```
?- flatten_no_cut([A,B,C], Flatted).
ERROR: Out of global-stack.
```

A solution that works correctly in the presence of variables is:

```
flatten(List, Flatted) :-
    flatten(List, [], Flatted).

flatten(Var, Tail, [Var| Tail]) :-
    var(Var),
    !.
flatten([], Flatted, Flatted) :-
    !.
flatten([Head| Tail], List, Flatted) :-
    !,
    flatten(Tail, List, Aux),
    flatten(Head, Aux, Flatted).
flatten(Head, Tail, [Head| Tail]).
```

Sample calls:

```
?- flatten([A,B,C], Flatted).
Flatted = [A, B, C].

?- flatten([A,[B,1,[a,foo(X)]],C], Flatted).
Flatted = [A, B, 1, a, foo(X), C].
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo for the remark. Without cuts (and var/1), Prolog loose a lot of practical usefulness... but I'm not expert on the deeper semantic of clauses, maybe I should post a question about scope of cuts. Does grouping goals by parenthesis changes the cut' scope ?

Comment: @CapelliC Not sure I understand your question. But, in this particular case, `flatten/2` is not a predicate that makes sense to worry about reversibility and thus the use of non-logical control constructs such as negation and conditionals doesn't hinder any practical use.

Comment: Indeed, it's a poorly formulated question, not related to the actual predicate discussed (I'm going to implement cuts in hitchhicker prolog). Sorry for the noise. Thanks anyway